# Django: Different level of logging on server and locally

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi, django-logging

I've set the logging level to INFO for loggers and handlers. Everything works as expected when I run Django on my local machine with `./manage.py runserver`. However, on Apache server with WSGI, the log contains only WARNING logs.

The `DEBUG` variable is set to `True` in both cases. Here is critical part of my `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'normal': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/clawd.log',
            'formatter': 'normal'
        },

        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'normal'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

State of the log after GET request on the local machine:

```
INFO 2018-01-18 22:07:38,935 basehttp "GET /case/new/doc/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 337
```

On the server:

Any idea how could that happen? How Django even knows that it is running on a server when the DEBUG flag is still True?

Comment: Have you got a `local_settings.py` ?

Comment: No, only `settings.py`.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you resolve your problem?

Comment: I didn't solve it, my workaround was printing INFO logs in WARNING category.